# Framework base classes with jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I use Play Framework 2 with Ebean now, but looks like question fits any JPA ORM, so feel free to suggest Hibernate, TopLink and other solutions.

I want to design some base classes for social network constructing. In my opinion it should be  class hierarchy where each class have few basic fields, like ids, names, descriptions and relationships with other classes. Framework users can inherit this classes and specialize them by adding required fields. Lets consider an example:

**Framework classes**

```
@MappedSuperclass
class AbstractUser {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String login;
    String password;

    @ManyToMany
    Set<AbstractGroup> groups;
}

@MappedSuperclass
class AbstractGroup {
    @Id
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

**My social network using framework classes**

```
@Entity
class MyUser extends AbstractUser {
    String name;
    String surname;
}

@Entity
class MyGroup extends AbstractGroup {
    String groupDescription;
}
```

All I want here is to extend AbstractUser and AbstractGroup classes with few fields with keeping their relationship.

Without JPA it could be solved with generics for example, or maybe with DI. But how to implement such an idea with JPA? 
Is it possible?

Comment: I was wondering if there is some good solution for this. Unfortunately you can't use references to classes which are not entities. That means that framework classes must be entities. One of the possible solutions I was thinking of is to use aspects to extend framework entities. Let us know how did you solved it.

Comment: @igo, to be honest I switched project to scala, throw out jpa and doing mapping with two functions, each is one-line :)
So generally say, I didn't solve problem, but significantly reduce amount of code.